# Quick way to get the assigned media format for DirectShow pin that does not support IAMStreamConfig?

Tags: delphi, debugging, filter, directshow

When a pin connection problem arises in my Delphi 6 (with DSPACK) DirectShow application I like to get the media format currently assigned to the pins involved in the connection.  I do this by querying the IAMStreamConfig interface if the pins supports it.  I am finding that some pins do not.  Is there another reliable way to quickly get the media format currently assigned to a pin that does not support IAMStreamConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `IPin::ConnectionMediaType` gets you connection media type, the type the pins have agreed on
- `IAMStreamConfig::GetFormat` gets you media type of unconnected yet pin, the type is about to be 'preferred' for the supposed connection

Comment: Thanks @Roman R.  That's a good distinction to know about between the two calls.